# Using a vector graphic as a custom form shape

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to use a vector graphic as a custom form shape in a WPF application so that if the user wants to resize the application, the vector graphic can be recalculated dynamically and redrawn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  In fact, the bulk of the "drawing" API in WPF is this way already.

The [Shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.aspx) class and it's subclasses provide a retained mode, vector graphics based drawing mechanism, which handles scaling and transforms easily.  See [Shapes and Basic Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx) for details.

Comment: If I'm using SVG file format do I need a library or something to handle it or can WPF natively handle SVG? Or is there any vector format that it can handle natively?

Comment: @icemanind Xaml **is** the native format.  You can convert SVG to xaml - see: http://benpittoors.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/convert-svg-to-xaml/  (I've had good luck doing this in Inkscape)